# Error : Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. (opensuse15.0)

Tags: php, mongodb, fork, opensuse

I am trying to start mongodb on opensuse, but am getting this error message "**Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code.**
". It was working fine yesterday.
I installed mongo and also installed a **php plugin with mongodb** using

**sudo zypper in php-pear php-devel**

**sudo pecl install mongodb**

I can't figure out what is the problem.[image]

Comment: Make sure the data directory exists and is writeable by the mongod user.  Check the log file for additional details.

Comment: @Joe I added this : $ sudo mkdir -p /data/db , and it created the directory, but the mongod still did not start :/

Comment: Check the mongod log for more information - any specific error messages should be noted there.